# get changes without fast-forwarding

Tags: git, git-rebase

[image]

I want to get the changes that are in origin/master into my search-players-algorithm branch without getting the search-players-algorithm branch above the master.In other words I want to update my search-players-algorithm branch and keep it the same place. Is it possible ?
I have tried git merge origin/master --no-ff
but it merged the two branches and put the search-players-algorithm branch uptop

Comment: The relative position of the *labels* in any graph drawing is not that important since the graph could just be drawn with a different node at the top. The parent/child relationships of the individual nodes *do* matter. The commits, and the graph they represent, are precisely what matter; the labels are just a way to *find* some particular commit(s), starting with the commit to which any given label is attached, then working backwards through the parent linkages.

Comment: Perhaps you need need the objects in origin/master, not necessarily apply those changes to your branch? git fetch can do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have your cake and eat it. If you want to consume the latest changes from master, you'll have to rebase on top of it.

Comment: I dont get what is the purpose of --no-ff then..what is more recommended to do in this situation -
git merge origin/master --no-ff
or
git reset --hard origin/master

Comment: @MD10: `--no-ff` forces Git to make a merge commit, rather than doing a fast-forward. If your future plans call for that, you should do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to run `git fetch` so that you get the information from remote branches but without moving anything.